# how can I center a bootstrap modal in a scrolled window

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have been working on a project in which I have a lot of data. When I click on that row in the table it will open the modal for additional details but I am having a problem in how can I vertically center the modal when the window is been scrolled in the bottom. Please help me on this.

Comment: Where is your code failing?

Answer (score 0):

[http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy][1]

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-example">
  ...
  <div id="navbar-example">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
  ...
</body>
```